# ¿Cómo agrego la carpeta JsCookMenu a un proyecto de genexus?

Tags: genexus

Como agregar JSCookMenu en genexus estoy intentando crear un menu para una master pague ahora si tienen ejemplo o usar boostrap mejor aun

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que instalar el UserControl, ya sea de cualquiera de las siguientes formas:

**Automática**

1. Ejecutar GeneXus y buscar el user control deseado JSCookMenu en la Start Page.
   (En la Start Page, ir a la pestaña Marketplace y usar el box de
   búsqueda para encontrar el UC).
2. Click install
3. GeneXus preguntará si quieres instalar el UC, click YES
4. GeneXus preguntará si quieres reiniciar, click YES
5. Revisar que en la pestaña toolbox se agregó el UC en la sección User
   Controls.

**Manual**

1. Descargar el UC desde GeneXus Marketplace.
2. Descomprimir archivos
3. Copiarlos en la carpeta UserControls en el directorio de instalación
   de GX.
4. Ejecutar desde la consola GeneXus con el parámetro /install. Por ejemplo: **<GX_Installation_Path>\GeneXus /install**
5. Revisar que en la pestaña toolbox se agregó el UC en la sección User
   Controls.

Una vez instalado el UC, debes ir al web form del objeto donde quieras que aparezca el menú (en este caso la MasterPage), buscar el JSCookMenu en ToolBox y agregarlo a la pantalla haciendo drag and drop.